# PHP change the website content through language selection

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, .htaccess

I am doing a PHP, MySQL CMS based website for one of my clients. Currently we have three languages English, French and Flemish.

How can we achieve that, whenever we refresh the page, the url like

About.php --> http://www.url.com/about (For Eng)

About.php --> http://www.url.com/fr/about (For French)

I am using javascript for language seleciton, since i don't have enough knowledge in php.

### Header.php

```
<div class="lang_container">
<a href="javascript:void(0);"><img src="<?php echo SITE_PATH_COMMON; ?>images/lan-en.gif" alt="">ENG</a>
<ul>
<li><a href="javascript:void(0);"><img src="<?php echo SITE_PATH_COMMON; ?>images/lan-en.gif" alt="">ENG</a></li>
<li><a href="javascript:void(0);"><img src="<?php echo SITE_PATH_COMMON; ?>images/lan-fr.gif" alt="">FRE</a></li>
<li><a href="javascript:void(0);"><img src="<?php echo SITE_PATH_COMMON; ?>images/lan-fl.gif" alt="">FLE</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

### Javascript:

```
$(".lang_container ul li a").click(function() {
var text = $(this).html();
var text1 = $(this).text();
$(".lang_container > a").html(text);
$(".lang_container ul").hide();
updateQuery(text1);
}); 

function updateQuery(e)
{
dataString = e;
var siteStatus = $('#siteStatus').val();
var ourLocation = window.location.pathname.split('/').pop();
str = "";
if ((siteStatus=='1') && (dataString=="Eng")) {
str = "";
}
else if ((siteStatus=='1') && (dataString=="Fre")) {
str = "fr/";
}
else if ((siteStatus=='1') && (dataString=="Fle")) {
str = "fl/";
}
window.location.href="http://192.168.1.16:8066/"+str+ourLocation;
}
```

Thanks in Advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need the code that handles the page redirection, right?

One way to do this is to use javascript on the dropdown menu to perform the redirect to the new location.

```
<?php
    $page = array_pop(explode('/', $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']));
?>
<input type="hidden" id="page" value="<?php echo $page; ?>" />
<select id="lang">
    <option value="en">English</option>
    <option value="fr">Francais</option>
</select>

$('#lang').on('change',function(e) {
    switch($(this).val()) {
        case 'en':
            window.location = 'http://www.url.com/'+$('#page').val();
        break;
        case 'fr':
            window.location = 'http://www.url.com/fr/'+$('#page').val();
        break;
    }
});
```

If javascript isn't an option and you need a PHP-only solution (which means that your dropdown has a submit button) it might look like this:

```
<?php
    $page = array_pop(explode('/', $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']));
?>
<form action="langredirect.php" action="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="page" value="<?php echo $page; ?>" />
    <select name="lang">
        <option value="en">English</option>
        <option value="fr">Francais</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="GO" />
</form>
```

Then in langredirect.php you could do a redirect:

```
switch($_POST['lang']) {
    case 'en':
        header('Location: http://www.url.com/'.$_POST['page']);
        exit();
    break;
    case 'fr':
        header('Location: http://www.url.com/fr/'.$_POST['page']);
        exit();
    break;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. What should i do, if am having more than 25 pages... Remember i said it's CMS website.

Comment: You can extract the current page name and include that in the form and then use that in the redirect code using php. I'll update the answer for the PHP solution.

Comment: I forgot to mention, extract the page name using $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].